# Introducing random noise into point positions

Tags: r, leaflet

I am using R and Leaflet for R to plot 1000s of points. The raw data is imported to a data frame from SQL Server as British National Grid (BNG) coordinates (Transverse Mercator) which are then converted to lat/long using rgdal before outputting to a stand-alone html via from a Leaflet widget.

The BNG coordinates have been produced by geocoding postcodes and so, when >1 person has the same postcode the coordinate is the same.

I would like to add some random noise to the last 2-digits of each easting/northing coordinate so that all points are likely to be visible in Leaflet. What would be the simplest way to achieve this?

thanks

mike

Comment: Add `runif(1, -99, 99)` to each coordinate? Can you give a sample of your data?

Comment: Also take a look at the `jitter` function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two solutions to overplotting are

1. "jittering" the points by adding some random noise to their coordinates and
2. adding transparency to the point color so you can see point density.

`x=jitter(x), y=jitter(y)` will accomplish #1.

`col=scales::alpha("blue", 0.5)` will accomplish #2.

Comment: Brilliant - so easy when you know how. Jitter works great :)